# How to set the column layout in ext4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a problem with EXTJS 4.1 layout.

how to set the column layout for a panel in ext 4.1.

In mozilla its working fine.

But in IE, it was not rendering and moreover, IE is trying to close.

the sample code is,

```
          var panel1 = getPanel1();
          var panel2 = getPanel2();
          var panel3 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
           layout:{type:'table',columns:2},
           title:'Panel3',
           items:[panel1,panel2],
           renderTo:Ext.getBody()
          });
```

Please give me a solution to render the panels in columns in ext4.1 ....

Answer (score 0):

A way that I know works because I do it in my code is to use a hbox layout.  I believe this is an equivalent layout for your example:

```
var panel1 = getPanel1();//make sure this panel contains flex: .5
var panel2 = getPanel2();//make sure this panel contains flex: .5
var panel3 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
   layout:{type:'hbox'},
   title:'Panel3',
   items:[panel1,panel2],
   renderTo:Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example that they show in the documentation?

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Layout',
    width: 350,
    height: 250,
    layout:'column',
    items: [{
        title: 'Column 1',
        columnWidth: 0.50
    },{
        title: 'Column 2',
        columnWidth: 0.50
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```